# Best Formatter to display an editable array of integers? (possible starting with 0)

Tags: java, swing, text, formatting

I'm using a JFormattedTextField as its container. I don't know how I could do this with NumbeFormatter, it converts everything to int, so.. yeah. Couldn't really do it with MaskFormatter either, it forces the input to fit the original mask, in my case 8 digits ("########"). Any number of digits (max 8) should be okay. Please help.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: What does "8 digits" and "any number of digits" mean?  If you don't need an int, what do you need?

Comment: I need an array of ints.

Comment: What exactly is an _"editable array of integers"_ and how exactly does that appear in (or have to do with) the text field?

Comment: So basically you just want a test field that allows only numbers and up to 8?

Comment: It looks exactly like a normal integer value, but logically digits are not connected and it is allowed to have 0 as the first digit. It works techically as a string too, with the formatter constantly checking if the character is digit (Character.isDigit() ~ "#" mask). But MaskFormatter has a static number of character in it, it's not resizeable, that's the problem.

Comment: Yes, allows only numbers, even those with 0 as first character, and with a size of max 8.

Comment: No, the number of maximum possible digits is 8 -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Yes, allows only numbers, even those with 0 as first character, and with a size of max 8"

Just use a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) (for the underlying document of the text field) to filter out anything that's not a number, and also to filter out out anything that causes the text field's document's length to be longer than eight.

Here's an example

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TestFieldToArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                final JTextField field = getFilteredField();
                final JTextField field2 = getFilteredField();
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                panel.add(field);
                panel.add(field2);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
            }
        }); 
    }

    static JTextField getFilteredField() {
        JTextField field = new JTextField(15);
        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument) field.getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {

            private final int maxChars = 8;

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length,
                    String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
                int docLength = fb.getDocument().getLength();
                if (docLength < maxChars) {
                super.replace(fb, offs, length,
                        str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", ""), a);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str,
                    AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
                int docLength = fb.getDocument().getLength();
                if (docLength < maxChars) {
                    super.insertString(fb, offs,
                            str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", ""), a);
                }        
            }
        });
        return field;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great, now I just wonder how to pick out the spaces between every 3 chars. If it has focus there are no spaces, if it loses the focus there are, hm.

Comment: I don't really know what that means _"pick out spaces"_. As far as I know, spaces aren't allowed

Comment: I updated my asnwer with a little picture. The NumberFormat has a handy method for getting rid of these spaces, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setGroupingUsed(boolean)), not sure how to use it when modifying the document directly.

Comment: Don't know what you're doing wrong. The new code I have above doesn't do that

Comment: I'm using JFormattedTextField, where I change its document like this: `surviveText.setDocument(setRuleDoc(surviveText.getDocument()));` 
with ur method a little modified: `private AbstractDocument setRuleDoc(Document dc){etc}`
And actually this doesn't really work, if the number of digits exceeds the maximum I get very weird numbers, minuses and 2147483647's. I appreciate your help anyways, I'm just gonna somehow find a workaround.

Comment: Next time post a runnable example code, so people dont have to guess what you're doing wrong. Will help you solve the problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Why should I need to post a runnable code when all the information required to solve the problem can be transferred in one sentence. Anyways, you already did a lot, so thank you.

Comment: How many questions did I have to ask you just to get an incomplete idea of what you're trying to do? Then when I give you an answer, you provide MORE information about what you're trying to do. Code helps us see what you are trying to do with your attempt. If your verbal description isnt great, at least those who are good at looking at code, can _tell_ what you are _attempting_ to do.

Comment: Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). These are the standards we would like to see from all questions. Though we rarely get it, if you want to be a respected user, you will try and adere to these guidelines. You'll notice reading it, that question, whenever possible, should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The questions you asked were already answered in my original post... I expressed it with total accuracy..

Comment: Sorry for stealing your time, everything works fine now with JTextFields.